# Import command not including word list in text file

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am trying to import a word list into a table in sqlite3 however, the error I am running into is that it doesn't insert the word into the table.
This is the error I receive: 0.out:1: expected 2 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL

I've tried different quotation with the variables in create table; same result. Also tried using different inserts such as LOAD DATA INFILE only to receive an error:

```
Error: incomplete SQL: LOAD DATA INFILE 0.out INTO TABLE data0(word)
```

============================

> sqlite3 $database.db << EOF
>
> CREATE TABLE $table(id INTEGER, word TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id));
>
> .import $text $table
>
> .exit
>
> EOF

============================

The text file has one word per line

```
all

all-inspiring
```

And when it is suppose to run properly would have an output like so:

```
CREATE TABLE data0 (id integer,word text, primary key(id));

INSERT INTO data0 VALUES(1,'all');

INSERT INTO data0 VALUES(2,'all-inspiring');

etc.
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your table has two columns. Whatever `.mode` you're using makes `.import` only see one column per record it reads, when it needs the same number for both table and record. Hence the warning about using null for the second column.

Comment: If you swap the order of the id and word columns you'll still get the warnings but it might work as you intend.

Comment: I've tried swapping id and word but it still has the same result. At the moment I have not specified a .mode when running this so what mode would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach might work :

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Make this a script so that side-effects are effectively wrapped
# without giving an end-user any hassle
file="tempfile"
nl -s, -w1 filename >> "$file"
# Above step makes a temporary CSV file for import adding line numbers in the beginning
database="yourdbname"
table="yourtablename"
sqlite3 "$database" <<EOF
CREATE TABLE ${table}(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,word TEXT);
.mode csv
.import $file $table
.exit
EOF
rm "$file" #Delete the temporary file
```

Take the above script for a spin.

**Verify**

```
sqlite3 yourdbname <<EOF
.separator ,
select * from yourtablename;
.quit
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks sjsam! the output is now exactly how I want it!